# Why is my program giving zero output?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am new to C++ and I am writing a c++ program that will simulate a colony of bunnies. The program will automatically add them, give them names, ages, etc. I am a bit confused on why my program is giving me this out. I have researched several ideas, but still seem to come out at a loss. On my attempts so far I have been focusing on getting a name to display. When the program executes the variables name, sex, color, don't return anything.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime> 
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void setSex();
char getSex();
void setColor(string color);
string getColor();
void setAge(int age);
int getAge();
void setName(string name);
string getName();
void printBunny();
int randomGeneration(int x);

//static std::string  POSSIBLE_NAMES = 18;
//static std::string   POSSIBLE_COLORS = 4;

static std::string possibleNames[] ={
    "Jen",
    "Alex",
    "Janice",
    "Tom",
    "Bob",
    "Cassie",
    "Louis",
    "Frank",
    "Bugs",
    "Daffy",
    "Mickey",
    "Minnie",
    "Pluto",
    "Venus",
    "Topanga",
    "Corey",
    "Francis",
    "London",
};
static std::string possibleColors[] ={

    "White",
    "Brown",
    "Black",
    "Spotted"
}; 

struct Bunny
{
    public:

        string name;
        int age;
        string color;
        char sex;

        Bunny(){
            name = "";
            age = 0;
            color = "";
        }
        Bunny(string name, string color, int age){

            name = name;
            color = color;
            age = age;
            setName(name);
            setColor(color);
            setAge(age);

        }

        //radioactive_mutant_vampire_bunny(radioactive_mutant_vampire_bunny)

        /*bool sex;
        std::string name, color;
        int age;
        //string name;
        bool radioactive_mutant_vampire_bunny;*/

    int randomGeneration(int x){
        return rand() % x;
    }
    void setSex()
    {
        int randomNumber = 1 + rand() % 2;

        ( randomNumber == 1 ) ? sex = 'm' : sex = 'f';
    }

    char getSex() 
    {
        return sex;
    }

    void setColor(string color)
    {
        //color = possibleColors[ 0 + rand() % POSSIBLE_COLORS ];
    }

    string getColor() 
    {
        return color;
    }

    void setAge(int age)
    {
        age = 0;
    }

    int getAge() 
    {
        return age;
    }

    void setName(string name)
    {
        int i = randomGeneration(18);
        name = possibleNames[i];
        //name = possibleNames[ 0 + rand() % POSSIBLE_NAMES ];
    }

    string getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    void printBunny() 
    {
        cout << "Name: " << getName() << endl;
        cout << "Sex: " << getSex() << endl;
        cout << "Color: " << getColor() << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << getAge() << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

    vector< Bunny > colony;

    cout << "Welcome to Bunny Graduation!" << endl << endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
    {
        colony.push_back( Bunny() );
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
    {
        colony[ i ].printBunny();
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I receive:

```
enter code here
Welcome to Bunny Graduation!

Name:
Sex: ▒
Color:
Age: 0

Name:
Sex: ▒
Color:
Age: 0

Name:
Sex: ▒
Color:
Age: 0

Name:
Sex: ▒
Color:
Age: 0

Name:
Sex: ▒
Color:
Age: 0
```

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? What did you expect?

Comment: You never assign (or initialize) `sex`, so it contains indeterminate value (and `color` is initialized to an empty string).

Comment: @KerrekSB I am confused on why `name:` doesn't output anything. I was expecting it to return the value of name.

Comment: But what would you expect to be the value of the `name`. You do not assign a name somewhere in your code. Yes, the return value of the name is correct, which is an empty string. `Bunny(string name, string color, int age)` - this constructor nowhere is called.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi i would expect the value of `name` to return a value from the `possibleNames` array.  Would I call that constructor inside of the method `setName`?

Comment: I did post an answer, hopefully will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is broken in so many ways, I rather give some kind of implementation hoping that the end result is what you expect.

Please note, this code does not represent the actual C++1x standards, it was published for educational purpose only.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int  POSSIBLE_NAMES = 18;
const int  POSSIBLE_COLORS = 4;

static std::string possibleNames[] ={
    "Jen",
    "Alex",
    "Janice",
    "Tom",
    "Bob",
    "Cassie",
    "Louis",
    "Frank",
    "Bugs",
    "Daffy",
    "Mickey",
    "Minnie",
    "Pluto",
    "Venus",
    "Topanga",
    "Corey",
    "Francis",
    "London",
};
static std::string possibleColors[] ={

    "White",
    "Brown",
    "Black",
    "Spotted"
};

struct Bunny
{
public:

string name;
int age;
string color;
char sex;

Bunny(){
    setSex();
    setColor();
    setAge(0);
    setName();
}

int randomGeneration(int x){
    return rand() % x;
}

void setSex()
{
    int randomNumber = randomGeneration(2);

    ( randomNumber == 1 ) ? sex = 'm' : sex = 'f';
}

char getSex()
{
    return sex;
}

void setColor()
{
    int randomNumber = randomGeneration(POSSIBLE_COLORS);
    color = possibleColors[randomNumber];
}

string getColor()
{
    return color;
}

void setAge(int age)
{
    this->age = age;
}

int getAge()
{
    return age;
}

void setName()
{
    int i = randomGeneration(POSSIBLE_NAMES);
    name = possibleNames[i];
}

string getName()
{
    return name;
}

void printBunny()
{
    cout << "Name: " << getName() << endl;
    cout << "Sex: " << getSex() << endl;
    cout << "Color: " << getColor() << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << getAge() << endl;
}
};

int main()
{

vector< Bunny > colony;

cout << "Welcome to Bunny Graduation!" << endl << endl;

for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
{
    colony.push_back( Bunny() );
}

for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
{
    colony[ i ].printBunny();
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, how does the methods know about the variables inside of `struct Bunny`?

Comment: @RileyThomas I don't want to be mean, but you should know what a constructor is. When you insert a new bunny in your vector (`colony.push_back( Bunny() );`) the constructor if the `Bunny` is called (this code: `Bunny(){
    setSex();
    setColor();
    setAge(0);
    setName();
}`) The constructor execute the setters.

Comment: the methods such as, `setSex` `setName` `getName` `setName`, etc. I felt like the methods belonged outside of the struct but when I put them outside of the struct I received a few errors claiming that the methods and variables were not declared.

Comment: I had a constructor but I believe I confused its use for the variables and not the methods

Comment: You should watch some tutorials/read some books about OOP in C++. Responding to your previous question, the setters should be member functions, otherwise they wont know for which bunny they set the variables.

Comment: thank you for this. It has really helped remove some of the confusion. As I look over the code a lot of questions I had are being answered.